# Cannot open database “binarystream” requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to use .net connect to SQL EXPRESS database. I also get error Cannot open database "binarystream" requested by the login. The login failed.

[image: See image here]

but my dataconnect already show I connected to databaseenter

[image: See image here]

here is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection dee= new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=binarystream;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES(@USERNAME,@PASSWORD)",dee);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2;
            dee.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dee.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can't use Integrated Security but you need to specify exactly the username and password. The error states that there is a problem with the user logging in

Comment: Integrated Security means you're using your domain user to log in - and looking at your gmail account in Azure, properly cannot use that. So enter your username and password in the connection string and check again

Comment: ok my user id is IDEA-PC\Administrator it is windows authentication,no password, what should be connection string?

Comment: @Lin Xiang, in your screenshots you have two servers: Azure and SQL Express. In your code sample you are trying to connect to SQL Express. Please confrim that you are having problem connecting to SQL Express (as opposed to Azure)

Comment: @Alex I have problem connect to the SQL EXPRESS

Comment: @Lin Xiang, make sure that the user account you are using to run your application is the same one used to open Visual Studio to connect to your database. Addittionally: you said "IDEA-PC\Administrator it is windows authentication,no password", this is a very bad security practise. You need to create a password.